# How to keep language after restart device?

Tags: android

i have problem with language change in my app. this is how i change language on button clic in my app

```
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale.ENGLISH; 
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

and work good but when i change language, my keyboard dont change in the new language and keep the system language and when i restart my device, my app doesn't keep the language changed.

how can i keep language after restart and make keyboard change language after language change.

Excuse me for my english.

thks

Comment: you need save one id or index on Database or Shared Preference for getting back language after restart

Comment: how can i do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use shared Preference

```
class my_activity extends Activity
 {
     SharedPreferences prefs;
     String lang;

        onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
        {
            //to retrieve the saved language 
          prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
          lang =prefs.getString("lang", "en");
           //lang = "en"or whatever the saved language before restarting the device
           //if there is no saved string with this key "lang" lang variable will be  
            equal "en"
        }
```

And when the language changes in the app on button click

```
{
    prefs.edit().putString("lang", lang).commit();
}
```

Comment: thks Menna-Allah Sami , i try and tell you what happens

Comment: thks work but how to change keyboard language if language of app change too ?